# Getting an error when my class contains two __init__ method with default and more parameters

Tags: python, class, python-3.4

I defined two `__init__` methods inside a class as I mentioned in the code snippet

```
class Employee:
   def __init__(self):
      print('This is init method')

   def __init__(self, workingHrs):
      print('This is init method with parameter')
```

Now when we use this class

```
employee = Employee()
employee = Employee(1)
```

It gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File, line 20, in <module>
employee = Employee()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'workingHrs'
```

My question is, how can I use both `__init__` methods with and without parameter except for the `self` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support [method overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) so when two methods have the same name the second one will replace the first one.

This can be solved by using an optional argument:

```
class Employee(object):
   def __init__(self, workingHrs=None):
      if workingHrs is None:
          print('This is init method')
      else:
          print('This is init method with parameter')
```

You could also use `classmethod`s to "implement" different constructors.